# Angular 4 - iterating in Nested JSON

Tags: json, angular, web-services, iteration

I have a web service that it eventually returns as JSON format. I am trying to iterate through this nested JSON and retrieve id with respect to their names. (This is a portion of my data). So I defined some names in order to find IDs. But I have a problem declaring function in component.ts. Any help please..?

**component**

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  results: any[];
  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe(res => {
        let names = ["Suan", "Mike"];

        names.forEach(name => {
          this.findLastValue(name);
        })

      },
      error => console.log(error)
    )
  }

  findLastValue(res, nameToFind: String) {
    let index = res.ABC.D.findIndex(d => d.Name[d.Name.findIndex(name => name === nameToFind)]);
    console.log(res.ABC.D[index].G);
  }
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "D": [
            {
                "Name": [ "Susan" ],
                "F": [ "School_0" ],
                "id": [ "14" ]
            },
            {
                "Name": [ "Lydia" ],
                "F": [ "School_1" ],
                id": [ "284" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: * just need to get ids!

Comment: So the problem is that the code does not compile, throws error or is just not doing what you want?

Comment: it says that property 'findLastValue' does not exist on type 'void'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `findLastValue` method declaration. Actually the way you are trying to do it is just function declaration, so its not method of `AppComponent` class, and therefore you can not access it via `this.findLastValue()`.

Also you have to use arrow function on the `names.forEach` line, so context (`this` keyword) will be preserved.

You can fix that be declaring it like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  results: any[];
  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe(res => {
        let names = ["Suan, Mike"];

        names.forEach(name => {
          this.findLastValue(res, name);
        })

      },
      error => console.log(error)
    )
  }

  findLastValue(res, nameToFind: string) {
    let index = res.ABC.D.findIndex(d => d.Name[d.Name.findIndex(name => name === nameToFind)]);
    console.log(res.ABC.D[index].G);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you also changed the line with `names.forEach(name => {`?

Comment: btw you have also typo there in declaration, you have `let names = ["Suan, Mike"];`, thats declaration of array with single value of type string `"Suan, Mike"`. Also in your JSON you have `Susan`, not `Suan`. So it should be probably `let names = ["Susan", "Mike"];`

Comment: that's exactly what I have. please refer to updated code .

Comment: I guess its not the same error, right? I forget to add `res` argument to the method call. `this.findLastValue(name);` needs to be `this.findLastValue(res, name);`

Comment: you are right. I appreciate for your help . One last thing, how do I deploy this into html? Not sure if it's possible to get each id to display selectively.

Comment: I am just reading these in chrome console. I need to read this in html.. dose this make sense

Comment: So you want to pass those values to HTML markup, like for example to some `<div>` element?

Comment: yes, i am trying to deploy each ids in the table or something

Comment: Well just save the values to some class field (just like you have `results` field), and print that in the template. I guess this is above the scope of this question, feel free to open new one with better explanation of the problem and what you tried and what is not working...